# What, for Nietzsche, is a noble death?

Tags: theology, nietzsche, practical-ethics, nihilism

This thread [Why is Nietzsche so against Socrates?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14238/why-is-nietzsche-so-against-socrates) on Socrates and Jesus's death and the article that I linked to [there](http://www.minerva.mic.ul.ie//vol10/Jesus.html), got me glibly wondering...

[In](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/37841/37841-h/37841-h.html) *Human, All to Human*, Nietzsche says that

> How One Dies is Indifferent.—The whole way in which a man thinks of
>   death during the prime of his life and strength is very expressive and
>   significant for what we call his character. But the hour of death
>   itself, his behaviour on the death-bed, is almost indifferent.

But we also know that he praised Jesus's death and says in his Notebooks

> It lacks any reason to say with Paul, that Jesus died "for the sins of
>   others,"... he died for his own "sin". Under other conditions found
>   inside, for example in the middle of the Europe of today, would the
>   same kind of person to live to teach as a nihilist

Piecing these scraps together, might he be getting to the idea that I die a noble death if I die for everyone's indifference to my demise?

Is Jesus's "sin" that we killed him?

Nietzsche was not successful in his lifetime...

Comment: The scraps you have linked here certainly say nothing about nihilism being worthy of death, and the other possible interpretation of what you've said, that death is the only thing that makes a nihilist indifferent to death is death itself, seems unlikely. If you are implying that Jesus was indifferent to his death, it is reported that he cried blood just thinking about it.

Comment: indifference isn't resignation RE jesus. i can't parse your first sentence, sorry

Comment: i guess you think that his sin was our sin? that's a confusing rhetorical turn to make by N. if so, and maybe won't preclude J. being the only christian... what do you think his sins were  ?

Comment: I would argue that resignation is what he had, but certainly not indifference. Your latest comment sounds like more questions. The sentence of mine that you could not parse is the important one. What it boils down to is that no, I cannot see any reason those two pieces of text imply that a nihilist must die for his indifference to death, no matter which way I try to read that final question.

Comment: ok i'll add to the question

Comment: "Nietzsche is at a remove from Schopenhauer for the fact that, under the guise of the Dionysian, the eventuality of death is an occasion not for resignation but for affirmation."

i v much doubt nietzsche would acclaim the death of someone who is simply resigned to their death...

Comment: Your latest updates have made this a much more understandable question.

Comment: "Nietzsche is dead." -- God

Comment: "Nietzsche is God" -- Death